# PHP variable access errors appear suddenly, and repaired by simply editing/saving relevant file with no actual changes. What could be causing this?

Tags: php, linux, lamp, litespeed

My website has been running fine with minimal changes for 12 months+

Recently, certain fatal PHP errors started appearing and breaking the website, always related to Class variable access. E.g.

```
PHP Fatal error: Access level to ClassName::$Joins must be (as in class ClassName2) or weaker in /path/to/ClassName.class.php on line 0
```

and

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot access property ClassName\Index::$context in /path/to/Index.php on line 67
```

The first time these were noticed, they were fixed by changing the access level of the variable in question to public.

However, now, every few days, the error returns, without any changes having been made to the website. On every occasion, I have been able to fix it simply by downloading the class file, applying a minor change (e.g. a space) and re-uploading it.

It's almost like the server starts accessing an old version of the file, until an updated version is uploaded. There is no evidence of old files having been restored or overwriting the file though, as modified date displays as per my last fix. Also, when downloading the file from FTP, the fix is already in there.

It doesn't make sense that this would be a code issue to me, it seems environmental, but I don't know.

I'm running on very reliable shared cpanel hosting.
Red Hat Linux
Litespeed v7.5
PHP version is 5.6.40

Can anyone suggest things that might be causing this?

Comment: did you do some server upgrade?

Comment: @GiacomoM It's a shared server. I'm sure they are always upgrading/maintaining. but nothing major I'm aware of.

Comment: @Baraka check your php.ini file, you should get a key from there

Answer (score 1):

If there are no changes at all to the site, and when you download the source it appears correct, then you should contact your hosting provider. It sounds like something is going wrong with your web server. Explain to the hosting company what has happened, and request that the web server be re-started (at a convenient time possibly).

The point about PHP 5.6 remains - which is End of Life (at end 2018). That itself is a vunerability to your site. You should seriously consider upgrading to PHP 7. Apart from the security regards you get a big performance improvement also.

Comment: There is no evidence that the source file is actually changing.
File modified time has not changed.
When you download it from the server, the code is exactly the same.

Comment: @Baraka ok I misunderstood your post. I've updated answer.